# Permutation of a string is failing for string having duplicate character

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, backtracking, recursive-datastructures

I am trying to understand how backtracking works. I am working on permutation of a string.

```
class Solution {
public:
    void permute(string s,int count[], string res, int level, vector<string> &perS)
    {
        if( level == s.size())
        {
            //cout<<res<<endl;
            perS.push_back(res);
            return;
        }
        int i;
        for(i=0; i<s.size(); i++)
        {
            if(count[i]==0)
            {
                continue;
            }
            res += s[i];
            count[i]--;
            permute(s, count, res, level+1, perS);
            count[i]++;
            //this line is problem I think?? how to handle if s1 contains duplicates??
            res.erase(res.end()-1);
        }
        
    }
    
    bool checkInclusion(string s1, string s2) {
        map<char, int> mp;
        for(int i=0; i<s1.size(); i++)
        {
            mp[s1[i]]++; 
        }
        int *count = new int[mp.size()];
        set<char> us;
        //to generate the count array of all the characters
        for(int i=0; i<s1.size(); i++)
        {
            us.insert(s1[i]);
        }
        auto it = us.begin();
        for(int i=0; i<mp.size(); i++)
        {
            count[i] = mp[*it++]++;
        }
        
        string res;
        vector<string> perS;
        permute(s1, count, res, 0, perS);
        
        //check if s2 contains in pers;
        
        for(string x:perS)
        {
            if(s2.find(x)!=string::npos)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

The above code works when I pass s1 as "helo" but give stackoverflow error if it has duplicates in it ex. "hello".

The algorithm I am trying to understand is very simple. we select a character from the string and traverse the other characters. once we reach the end we backtrack and check other options.

I tried but not able to understand why it fails for string having duplicates.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nYFd7VHKyWQ&t=1346s
I am trying the same algo explained in the above url, but I am trying to code it in cpp language.

I would really appreciate any input on this. This is my first question so pardon me for any error. it will help me visualise the recursive flow for backtracking problem.

Comment: Notice that std has [`std::next_permutatiuon`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation).

Comment: Generating the permutation seems to be a brute force approach, sorting input seems to allow better algorithm.

Comment: Lets forget about the algorithm and focus on your goal... what kind of permutation are you looking for? Permutation with or without repetition? Permutation of the input string or permutation of the unique character set derived from the input string? Please include all relevant details about your goal in the question. I won't watch an [any length] youtube video for additional information.

Comment: Thank you for replying @grek. I am trying to generate permutation of a string which contains duplicate characters. The code given above, works and generate all permutation of a string which has all unique character like "abc" but doesn't work on the string like "abbc". 
Permutation can repeat. like we can consider ab1b2c and ab2b1c (b1 denotes the first b and b2 denotes the second b) as two different permutation. My goal is to only generate all possible permutation of the given string.

Comment: @Jarod42 yes, there are many other approaches available for solving the same problem. I am trying to solve it by backtracking to understand the recursive nature of the algorithm.